# Windows 10 does not boot after Ubuntu 16.04 installation

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, boot-repair

Can someone please give me a hand? I had a fully functioning Windows10, then decided to install dual-booting Ubuntu and now the system boots into Ubuntu, but I cant get back to my Windows. I have tried boot options via F12 but there is only Ubuntu.

Here is [the report from boot-repair](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24242309/).

I really need to recover my data, please help me.
Thank you very much for any advice.

Comment: Have you tried with Chrome?  Chrome has most things built-in to make things like YouTube work without needing extra plugins.

Comment: `os-prober` might be missing in your ubuntu installation which means grub cant find windows. Install it and then update grub, may help.

Comment: Did you leave Windows 10 always on hibernation or fast boot on? Then Linux NTFS driver cannot see the NTFS partition. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions Turn off fast start in Windows. You may temporarily have to reinstall Windows boot loader to MBR with Windows repair or install disk's repair console. Then use Boot-Repair to reinstall grub. How to restore the Ubuntu/XP/Vista/7/8/10 BIOS bootloader 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader &
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System

Answer (score 2):

According to http://paste.ubuntu.com/24242309/ you don't need to recover your data since you did't loose your NTFS partition **or any sort of data**, it seem that you just **can't boot** to windoze.

Let's try to solve this.

Press **Ctrl+Alt+T** to open a terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo shutdown -r now
```

**IF** you still can't boot to windoze from GRUB **do a recovery from your windoze cd** to boot back again to the windoze BUT you will end up **not be able to boot to Ubuntu** for sure, check a tutorial how to install Ubuntu along side with windoze maybe is something you missed?

You can **again** always try to use boot-repair live cd: https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/ **after** you successful restore the boot loader of Micro$oft to be able to **boot both** Ubuntu and windoze.

Hope it helps